# iframe Https site in UIWebView of iOS app - suddenly stops working (..but not in safari)

Tags: html, ios, iframe, uiwebview, safari

I've just submitted an app to the Appstore that **iframes an Https site** (not mine) in `UIWebView` in one of the view controllers. The "framing" **worked perfectly for about a week**, then suddenly *something happened*. As of its sudden occurrence, I suspect the host of the framed site might have done something to protect my framing. I'm pretty sure that's not the case as it worked a couple of days ago and they **rarely make updates to their site**.

### What now happens

Let me explain this a bit further. A few days ago, one could **submit data through the WebView inside the app** (which is the only purpose of the WebView) but now, all of a sudden trying to submit data generates to a custom error: **"Something wen wrong, please contact system administrators"**. **Not a 404** error or something, just a "custom error" that says that something went wrong. But, if one opens my iframe .html doc in **mobile safari**, submitting data inside the iframe **works just fine**. No errors are displayed in the console for my iframe html doc, except a **favicon error** but I'm sure that has nothing to do with it. I've also tried **moving the file over to a different domain** in case they've blacklisted my first domain but that didn't help.
(The company who owns this https site has granted me permission to frame their site in my app but they're really not that cooperative so asking them what happen will lead to nothing. I have of course, but no answer.)

I do realize this is probably something I should ask them about, but as they're not responding as it worked before, I'm guessing this could be the cause of something else. **Any ideas what else I could try? Why does it work in safari but not in UIWebView (anymore)**? I know, UIWebView != safari, but except from that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the remote server is filtering the user agent of the UIWebView.... Not sure.

Comment: OK what does that mean? Any way to by pass it? And why do you think it worked just fine a couple of days ago. I'm almost positive they haven't implemented any new security features.

Comment: Here is what a user agent is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent
But it means there is a new security feature :/. If it worked a couple of days ago they surely changed something if you did not on your side.
You should ask them, we can't know at this point.